# How to create Firebase storage object from Firebase storage url

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

When a file is upload to Firebase Storage, you can access an object representing the file in a Firebase Cloud Function via the storage.object().onFinalize() event. This object provides properties such as `bucket` and `name`.

For example, you might set up the following to access the file when it is created:

```
exports.generateThumbnails = functions
    .storage.object()
    .onFinalize(async fileOjbect => {
  // Do something here with the storage object (here named fileObject).
});
```

My question regards how to get that same object via the object storage url of the form:

```
gs://my-app.appspot.com/photos/new_photo_here.jpeg
```

I'm having trouble finding the documentation for creating the object from the url. I would like to pass the url to a constructor of some sort that returns the object so I can then access the `bucket` and `name` properties (without having to do any parsing on my own). Does such a constructor exist? If so where is it documented? Something like this:

```
const file = storage.object('gs://my-app.appspot.com/photos/new_photo_here.jpeg');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `firebase-admin` to get storage object from URL.
First, you should parse the bucket name from the URL inside your function.
Bucket name is followed by `gs://` in the URL.
Then the next session will be file path, and you can use `Bucket` object of `firebase-admin` to get storage object from this file path.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

function getFirebaseStorageObject(url) {
 const bucketName = url.match(/gs:\/\/([^\/]*)\//)[1]
 const filePath = url.replace(`gs://${bucketName}/`, '')
 
 return admin.storage().bucket(bucketName).file(filePath);
}

getFirebaseStorageObject('gs://my-app.appspot.com/photos/new_photo_here.jpeg');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in the [Cloud Storage Node.js Client API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/index.html) that allows to create a Storage object from the object storage url.

You will need to parse the url on your own, as you have mentioned, in such a way you get the `bucket` and the object `name`, in order to combine the [`bucket()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html#bucket) and [`file()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#file) methods.

Note that the bucket name value that you pass to the `bucket()` method should not contain the `gs://` "protocol" part.